# How to capture hovermouse event in designmode for winform UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm building a user control with two control inside it (a Label and a textbox).  When a user drags the user control onto a WinForm, I want to allow them to use their mouse as a splitter control to control the label/textbox proportions in the box.  I tried to wire up the hover event in the control, but it's only in affect during runtime..  How can I do it in DesignMode.???
[image]
Example:

```
    private void NgoUserControl_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control c = sender as Control;
        Point pos = c.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

        c.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;

        //
        // resize logic
        // 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fire events during design-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399260/fire-events-during-design-time)

Comment: You can create a custom designer and use a glyph. Copy the code of the example and see it in action: [How to: Extend the Appearance and Behavior of Controls in Design Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms171820(v=vs.140)).

Comment: like the Glyph example..  But very complex..  It'll take awhile to figure it out  (sigh)...